# After creating a table in prostgresql through the node JS, Password regex is not working when I try to use the insert query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

After executing the below node js code, user table was created successfully and able to see it in pgAdmin as well.

```
import { pool } from '../models/pool';
const createUsersTable = `
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  firstName VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(firstName) BETWEEN 3 AND 150),
  lastName VARCHAR(86),
  userEmail TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (LENGTH(userEmail) BETWEEN 5 AND 280),
  mobileNumber TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (mobileNumber ~ '^([0|\+[0-9]{2})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$'),
  password VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (password ~ '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$'),
  gender VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (gender IN ('MALE','FEMALE','OTHERS'))
  )
  `;



export const executeQueryArray = async (arr) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const stop = arr.length;
    arr.forEach(async (q, index) => {
      await pool.query(q);
      if (index + 1 === stop) resolve();
    });
  });
export const createTables = () => executeQueryArray([createTableQueries]);
```

But when I try to execute the user insert query with password value as Abcd@1234 it is not working and it is saying invalid password_check . can any one help me out to solve this issue ? ****

Comment: You should not be storing anything but **hashed passwords** in that column, preferably using something at least as good as [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Comment: What if my given name is Bo or Ty?

Comment: HI @tadman , I do agree with out but, here I am not able to find what was the exact issue. I check the above password regex in other 3rd party sites and it is accepting Abcd@1234 value , but when I try to insert in postgresql admin it is thronging error